# Defining the Set of Rational Numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, predicate-logic, multisets

I was wondering about how to define the set of rational numbers, as I am currently learning about set theory in a class of mine. We were going through using set builders to define sets and produced two different ways of defining the set of Rational Numbers ($\mathbb{Q}$):

Definition 1: $\mathbb{Q} = \lbrace \frac{a}{b} \vert \ (a \in \mathbb{Z})  \ \wedge (b \in \mathbb{Z}) \ \wedge (b \not= 0) \rbrace$

Definition 2: $\mathbb{Q} = \lbrace x \vert \exists a,b \in \mathbb{Z}, \ x = \frac{a}{b} \rbrace$

Definition 1 introduced the concept of a "multiset," since multiple instances of the same element will occur (for example, $\frac{1}{2} = \frac{2}{4} = \frac{3}{6} = 0.5$) in the set defined by Definition 1.

**My first question is whether Definition 2 would also produce a multiset.**

It is my instinct that Definition 2 would not produce a multiset, since it is simply asking the question "Given some numerical value, are there two integers whose quotient equals that value?" and answering "If so, that value is in the set of rational numbers". Therefore, something like the value of $0.5$ (imagined purely as a value, a point on a number line for example) would only be included once since even though it can be described as the quotient of two integers in many different ways, the set is not asking for those different expressions but just the value that the expressions describe.

**My second question is whether it is necessary to include the proposition $b \not= 0$ in Definition 2.**

My instinct here is that this condition is *not* necessary for Definition 2, since it would be impossible to produce any value x by taking the quotient of an integer and $0$, so given any value $x$, there won't exist a quotient $\frac{a}{0}$ (where a is an integer) that will yield $x$.

__

Thanks!

Comment: Definition 1 is decidedly shaky in a set-theoretic context -- multisets are really best left to computer scientists. Definition 2 is much better; if you don't want to worry about whether $b$ can be $0$, you can just say $\Bbb Q=\{x\;\vert\;\exists a,b\in\Bbb Z, bx=a\}$.

Comment: Even more commonly, one defines $\Bbb Q$ as $\{(a,b)~:~a\in\Bbb Z,~b\in\Bbb Z\setminus \{0\}\}/\simeq$ where $\simeq$ is the equivalence relation $\{((a,b),(c,d))~:~ad=bc\}$ over $\Bbb Z\times (\Bbb Z\setminus \{0\})$, that the elements can be thought of as equivalence classes of the $\simeq$ relation.

Comment: That said, with you writing it in your first set as $\frac{a}{b}$ rather than as $(a,b)$, I disagree that the first produced a multiset.  You were *redundant* in how you listed them, but the element $0.5$ only occurs as an element in the set a single time... just as every other set elements are either elements or are not elements.  There is no concept of being an element multiple times.  Unless we were explicitly told to treat it as a multiset then there is no reason to treat it as a multiset.

Comment: As for why we insist on $b$ not being zero, that can be seen as historical or as being necessary for the definition of the relation $\simeq$ I alluded to earlier since without the restriction the relation would no longer be transitive, else $(0,1)\simeq (0,0)\simeq (1,0)$ but $(0,1)\not\simeq (1,0)$